# File Upload from a .net MVC Bootstrap Modal page works in IE but not in Edge or Chrome or in Firefox

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am writing a .net MVC 4.7 web application, most of it is working fine. One page has a series of Tabs each one representing a type of entity, one of which is Images. You can Create, edit, delete a file that represents a picture of the Provider that the page is for.  When you do a create/edit/delete a modal window pops up and lets you do the action that you have invoked. My problem comes up when Creating an Image, the modal pops up, you select the image type, select the file and include a comment then press the enter button to create the record in the database.  When I use the IE browser (v11) it works just fine but any other browser (Edge, Chrome and Firefox) does not work, the image Object that comes into the Create method has mostly null values, although the ProviderId value is in the Id field of the image object.  I can not figure out what is going on here. Using Bootstrap 3.3.7 and Jquery 3.4.1

```
   public ActionResult Create(int id)
    {
        Image image = new Image();
        image.ProviderId = id;

        //ViewBag.ProviderId = id;
        ViewBag.ImageTypeId = DataHelper.GetImageTypeSelectList(db, (String)Session["BusUnit"], null);
        //return PartialView("Create");
        return PartialView("Create", image);
    }

    // POST: Images/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="image"></param>
    /// <param name="File"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Image image, HttpPostedFileBase File)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (image.File.HasFile())
            {
                if (!image.File.IsSizeValid())
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("File", "File size must be less than 6 MB");
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        image.FileName = Path.GetFileName(image.File.FileName);
                        image.FileSize = image.File.ContentLength;
                        image.FileSystemType = image.File.ContentType;
                        image.FileContent = new byte[image.FileSize];
                        image.File.InputStream.Read(image.FileContent, 0, image.FileSize);
                        image.UploadDate = System.DateTime.Now;

                        //        if (image.File.IsImageFile())
                        //        {
                        //            System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(image.File.InputStream);
                        //            int height = img.Height;
                        //            int width = img.Width;
                        //        }
                        image.CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name.Replace("1UPMC-ACCT\\", "");
                        image.CreatedDate = System.DateTime.Now;
                        db.Images.Add(image);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        string url = Url.Action("Index", "Images", new { id = image.ProviderId });
                        return Json(new { success = true, url = url });
                    }
                    catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
                    {
                        StringBuilder message = DataHelper.GetAllEntityValidationErrorMsgs(e);
                        logger.ErrorFormat("Database validation Exception -> {0}", message, e);
                        ModelState.AddModelError(String.Empty, message.ToString());
                    }
                    catch (DbUpdateException s)
                    {
                        if (s.InnerException != null)
                        {
                            var sqlException = s.InnerException as System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException;
                            if (sqlException.InnerException != null)
                            {
                                var innerException = sqlException.InnerException as System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException;
                                if (innerException.Number == 2601 || innerException.Number == 2627)
                                {
                                    ModelState.AddModelError("File", "Duplicate File, you can not add this File for this Provider again.");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    String messages = DataHelper.GetAllExceptionMessages(s);
                                    logger.ErrorFormat("Exception thrown {0}", messages, s);
                                    ModelState.AddModelError(String.Empty, messages);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (System.Exception ex)
                    {
                        String messages = DataHelper.GetAllExceptionMessages(ex);
                        logger.ErrorFormat("Exception thrown {0}", messages, ex);
                        ModelState.AddModelError(String.Empty, messages);
                    }  // end of try catch block
                } // end of normal processing
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("File", "Select a File to upload.");
            }  // end of hasfile
        }
        else
        {
            var errors = ModelState.Where(m => m.Value.Errors.Count() > 0);
            foreach (var kvp in errors.ToList())
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, string.Format("{0}:{1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value.Errors[0].ErrorMessage));
            }
        } // end of is valid

        ViewBag.ProviderId = image.ProviderId;
        ViewBag.ImageTypeId = DataHelper.GetImageTypeSelectList(db, (String)Session["BusUnit"], image.ImageTypeId);
        return PartialView("Create", image);
    }
```

Here is the cshtml:

```
@model ProviderTracker.Models.Image
@using ProviderTracker.Models

<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria- 
hidden="true">&times;</button>
<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Create an Image</h4>
</div>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Images", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype ="multipart/form-data" }))
{
<div class="modal-body">

    @*@Html.AntiForgeryToken()*@

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProviderId)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImageTypeId, "Image Type", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("ImageTypeId", null, "Select...", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ImageTypeId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.File, "Select File :", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.File, new { @type = "file", @id="File", @class = "form-control" })
                @*@Html.FileFor(model => model.File, new { @class = "form-control" })*@
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.File, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comment, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comment, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "Comment" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comment, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Return to List</button>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save" />
</div>
}
```

Comment: Have you check the console error?

Comment: I looked at the Output window, there are no messages.